# I can't I see my latest commit on github?

Tags: github, git-commit

1) I push a commit to Github with `git push origin master`.

```
C:(...)[master]> git log
commit 35c4d94b2c6be21d2928d3725cc637090b48463c
... 
commit ed38979291835368e25466a136b2a0c84a56818c
...
```

2) On **github.com**, I refresh my project's commits page but can't see my latest commit.

Comment: are you sure you're looking at the master branch on github?

Comment: I am sure, `master` is the only branch I have.

Comment: This was weird but the problem apparently solved itself.  
It's **15:00**:  
1) I make another commit and push it  
2) I refresh the commits page on github  
3) I see both commits:  

- the one that I made at **14:10** which was missing 
- the one I made just now at **14:58**  
  
I can't explain this.

Comment: Had the same issue and making a commit with a small change in README.md pushed the rest so it could be visible on GitHub.